# Xamarin Sqlite Local file path

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, xamarin, local-database

I have an app (Xamarin.Forms cross platform) that uses `SQLite` to manipulate data locally. I have initialized the data values like this:

```
static UserDatabase database;

database = new UserDatabase(DependencyService.Get<ILocalFileHelper>().GetLocalFilePath("User.db3")); //sv67219.Diabetes_App.dbo"));
```

This seems to work perfectly, but i dont know where exactly is the database stored. In other words, where is **"User.db3"** stored? (Which folder?).

I want to know this because i want to view my database via DBBrowser. Coz without DBBrowser i have no idea what tables are being created and whats going on in the background (otherwise i use querying for each scenario to output values).

Thanks!

Comment: look at the implementation of ILocalFileHelper, or just check the return value of GetLocalFilePath()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** Go to following directory

> C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\lib\

**Step 2:**  click on the following application **monitor.exe**

[image]

**Step 3:** select the emulator

[image]

**Step 4:** Click on **data** folder and then again **data** folder

[image]

**Step 5:** Find your app (**com.xxx.xxxx.xxxx**) and then select **files** folder. Then you can see **xxxx.sql**