# Cant find sql lite file on android

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

I created a SQL Lite database and embbed in my app as a android asset the question is where the heck is the file stored on the device I used the following code to access the database

```
public Database()
{           
    var path = Path.Combine(System.Environment.
     GetFolderPath(System.Environment.
     SpecialFolder.Personal), "StockApp.db");

     Console.Write("OPening Database dbPath" + path);

     database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path);
 }
```

When I search for the file i cannot find it but when I use the internal debugger it puts the file at the following location.

It finds it fine and it does place a row in the table

path    "/data/user/0/com.companyname.StockApp/files/StockApp.db"   string

But where is the actual file I have a STK7 DEVICE for testing so Do any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=macos

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading sqlite file from asset folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857734/reading-sqlite-file-from-asset-folder)

Comment: @RaymondNijland i no where the file is in memory but i want the physicall file to look at it in sqllite studio

Comment: @rogue,If you want to get sqlite database local file path, I suggest you can take a look:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638086/xamarin-sqlite-local-file-path and https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/61402/how-to-access-a-database-file-when-the-device-is-connected-to-a-computer